# Background subtraction using Emgu CV

Tags: emgucv, background-subtraction

How can I implement background subtraction using Emgu CV?

Answer (score 3):

Yes this is quite possible take a look at the "MotionDetection" example provided with EMGU this should get you started.

Effectively the code that removes the foreground is effectively named "_forgroundDetector" it is the "_motionHistory" that presents stores what movement has occurred.

The example has everything you need if you have trouble running it let me know,

Cheer

Chris

See:[Removing background from _capture.QueryFrame()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7328693/removing-background-from-capture-queryframe/7331587#7331587)

Answer (score 0):

Check this:
http://www.oliveragustin.com/background-subtraction-in-c

Answer (score 0):

This question is old but in case someone is looking for a simple answer.

I had the same problem but on EmguCV 3.1.0 using the class Named `BackgroundSubtractor` ([Link to the class](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.1.0/document/html/f35e5e15-7a7a-f28e-324d-ffefaba231be.htm)) did the work for me.

Hope it can help someone