# Removing background from _capture.QueryFrame()

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I am using Emgucv and i would like to know if it possible to remove the background from a _capture.QueryFrame and to be able to focus on the nearest object on my camera?   Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is quite possible take a look at the "**MotionDetection**" example provided with EMGU this should get you started.

Effectively the code that removes the foreground is effectively named "_forgroundDetector" it is the "_motionHistory" that presents stores what movement has occurred.

The example has everything you need if you have trouble running it let me know,

Cheer

Chris